# How to merge 2 dataframe by date and time in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I want to match certain parts of 2 dataframes by date and time and merge them into one of them. But my code is not working.
I have 2 dataframe df and df2. First is df and second is df2. What can I do for this? I want to add Weather, Temp, Feels and after that to df.

[image]
[image]

here is the text verison of datafreames. It's just a sample because they are too big

```
{'road': {0: 10500,
  1: 10500,
  2: 10500,
  3: 105400,
  4: 105400,
  5: 106600,
  6: 14100,
  7: 22800,
  8: 22800,
  9: 22800},
 'date': {0: '2021.03.08 02:00:00',
  1: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  2: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
  3: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  4: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  5: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  6: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  7: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  8: '2021.03.08 01:45:00',
  9: '2021.03.08 05:45:00'}}
```

```
{'Il': {142738: 'ankara',
  142739: 'ankara',
  142740: 'ankara',
  142741: 'ankara',
  142742: 'ankara',
  142743: 'ankara',
  142744: 'ankara',
  142745: 'ankara',
  142746: 'ankara',
  142747: 'ankara',
  142748: 'ankara',
  142749: 'ankara',
  142750: 'ankara',
  142751: 'ankara',
  142752: 'ankara',
  142753: 'ankara',
  142754: 'ankara',
  142755: 'ankara',
  142756: 'ankara',
  142757: 'ankara',
  142758: 'ankara',
  142759: 'ankara',
  142760: 'ankara',
  142761: 'ankara',
  142762: 'ankara',
  142763: 'ankara',
  142764: 'ankara',
  142765: 'ankara',
  142766: 'ankara',
  142767: 'ankara',
  142768: 'ankara',
  142769: 'ankara',
  142770: 'ankara',
  142771: 'ankara',
  142772: 'ankara',
  142773: 'ankara',
  142774: 'ankara',
  142775: 'ankara',
  142776: 'ankara',
  142777: 'ankara'},
 'Lat': {142738: 40.13,
  142739: 40.13,
  142740: 40.13,
  142741: 40.13,
  142742: 40.13,
  142743: 40.13,
  142744: 40.13,
  142745: 40.13,
  142746: 40.13,
  142747: 40.13,
  142748: 40.13,
  142749: 40.13,
  142750: 40.13,
  142751: 40.13,
  142752: 40.13,
  142753: 40.13,
  142754: 40.13,
  142755: 40.13,
  142756: 40.13,
  142757: 40.13,
  142758: 40.13,
  142759: 40.13,
  142760: 40.13,
  142761: 40.13,
  142762: 40.13,
  142763: 40.13,
  142764: 40.13,
  142765: 40.13,
  142766: 40.13,
  142767: 40.13,
  142768: 40.13,
  142769: 40.13,
  142770: 40.13,
  142771: 40.13,
  142772: 40.13,
  142773: 40.13,
  142774: 40.13,
  142775: 40.13,
  142776: 40.13,
  142777: 40.13},
 'Lon': {142738: 33.1,
  142739: 33.1,
  142740: 33.1,
  142741: 33.1,
  142742: 33.1,
  142743: 33.1,
  142744: 33.1,
  142745: 33.1,
  142746: 33.1,
  142747: 33.1,
  142748: 33.1,
  142749: 33.1,
  142750: 33.1,
  142751: 33.1,
  142752: 33.1,
  142753: 33.1,
  142754: 33.1,
  142755: 33.1,
  142756: 33.1,
  142757: 33.1,
  142758: 33.1,
  142759: 33.1,
  142760: 33.1,
  142761: 33.1,
  142762: 33.1,
  142763: 33.1,
  142764: 33.1,
  142765: 33.1,
  142766: 33.1,
  142767: 33.1,
  142768: 33.1,
  142769: 33.1,
  142770: 33.1,
  142771: 33.1,
  142772: 33.1,
  142773: 33.1,
  142774: 33.1,
  142775: 33.1,
  142776: 33.1,
  142777: 33.1},
 'Tarih': {142738: '2021.03.07',
  142739: '2021.03.07',
  142740: '2021.03.07',
  142741: '2021.03.07',
  142742: '2021.03.07',
  142743: '2021.03.07',
  142744: '2021.03.07',
  142745: '2021.03.07',
  142746: '2021.03.07',
  142747: '2021.03.07',
  142748: '2021.03.07',
  142749: '2021.03.07',
  142750: '2021.03.07',
  142751: '2021.03.07',
  142752: '2021.03.07',
  142753: '2021.03.07',
  142754: '2021.03.07',
  142755: '2021.03.07',
  142756: '2021.03.07',
  142757: '2021.03.07',
  142758: '2021.03.07',
  142759: '2021.03.07',
  142760: '2021.03.07',
  142761: '2021.03.08',
  142762: '2021.03.08',
  142763: '2021.03.08',
  142764: '2021.03.08',
  142765: '2021.03.08',
  142766: '2021.03.08',
  142767: '2021.03.08',
  142768: '2021.03.08',
  142769: '2021.03.08',
  142770: '2021.03.08',
  142771: '2021.03.08',
  142772: '2021.03.08',
  142773: '2021.03.08',
  142774: '2021.03.08',
  142775: '2021.03.08',
  142776: '2021.03.08',
  142777: '2021.03.08'},
 'Saat': {142738: '00:00',
  142739: '03:00',
  142740: '06:00',
  142741: '09:00',
  142742: '12:00',
  142743: '15:00',
  142744: '18:00',
  142745: '21:00',
  142746: '00:00',
  142747: '03:00',
  142748: '06:00',
  142749: '09:00',
  142750: '12:00',
  142751: '15:00',
  142752: '18:00',
  142753: '21:00',
  142754: '00:00',
  142755: '03:00',
  142756: '06:00',
  142757: '09:00',
  142758: '12:00',
  142759: '15:00',
  142760: '18:00',
  142761: '00:00',
  142762: '03:00',
  142763: '06:00',
  142764: '09:00',
  142765: '12:00',
  142766: '15:00',
  142767: '18:00',
  142768: '21:00',
  142769: '00:00',
  142770: '03:00',
  142771: '06:00',
  142772: '09:00',
  142773: '12:00',
  142774: '15:00',
  142775: '18:00',
  142776: '21:00',
  142777: '00:00'},
 'Weather': {142738: 1,
  142739: 1,
  142740: 1,
  142741: 1,
  142742: 1,
  142743: 5,
  142744: 5,
  142745: 1,
  142746: 1,
  142747: 1,
  142748: 5,
  142749: 5,
  142750: 11,
  142751: 5,
  142752: 5,
  142753: 1,
  142754: 7,
  142755: 7,
  142756: 4,
  142757: 4,
  142758: 4,
  142759: 1,
  142760: 4,
  142761: 1,
  142762: 1,
  142763: 1,
  142764: 1,
  142765: 1,
  142766: 5,
  142767: 5,
  142768: 1,
  142769: 1,
  142770: 1,
  142771: 5,
  142772: 5,
  142773: 11,
  142774: 5,
  142775: 5,
  142776: 1,
  142777: 7},
 'Temp': {142738: 22,
  142739: 17,
  142740: 18,
  142741: 24,
  142742: 28,
  142743: 28,
  142744: 24,
  142745: 22,
  142746: 18,
  142747: 18,
  142748: 19,
  142749: 22,
  142750: 26,
  142751: 25,
  142752: 21,
  142753: 17,
  142754: 28,
  142755: 21,
  142756: 22,
  142757: 28,
  142758: 32,
  142759: 34,
  142760: 32,
  142761: 22,
  142762: 17,
  142763: 18,
  142764: 24,
  142765: 28,
  142766: 28,
  142767: 24,
  142768: 22,
  142769: 18,
  142770: 18,
  142771: 19,
  142772: 22,
  142773: 26,
  142774: 25,
  142775: 21,
  142776: 17,
  142777: 28},
 'Feels': {142738: 22,
  142739: 17,
  142740: 18,
  142741: 25,
  142742: 28,
  142743: 27,
  142744: 25,
  142745: 22,
  142746: 18,
  142747: 18,
  142748: 19,
  142749: 23,
  142750: 26,
  142751: 26,
  142752: 21,
  142753: 17,
  142754: 31,
  142755: 21,
  142756: 22,
  142757: 26,
  142758: 30,
  142759: 31,
  142760: 31,
  142761: 22,
  142762: 17,
  142763: 18,
  142764: 25,
  142765: 28,
  142766: 27,
  142767: 25,
  142768: 22,
  142769: 18,
  142770: 18,
  142771: 19,
  142772: 23,
  142773: 26,
  142774: 26,
  142775: 21,
  142776: 17,
  142777: 31},
 'Wind': {142738: nan,
  142739: nan,
  142740: nan,
  142741: nan,
  142742: nan,
  142743: nan,
  142744: nan,
  142745: nan,
  142746: nan,
  142747: nan,
  142748: nan,
  142749: nan,
  142750: nan,
  142751: nan,
  142752: nan,
  142753: nan,
  142754: nan,
  142755: nan,
  142756: nan,
  142757: nan,
  142758: nan,
  142759: nan,
  142760: nan,
  142761: nan,
  142762: nan,
  142763: nan,
  142764: nan,
  142765: nan,
  142766: nan,
  142767: nan,
  142768: nan,
  142769: nan,
  142770: nan,
  142771: nan,
  142772: nan,
  142773: nan,
  142774: nan,
  142775: nan,
  142776: nan,
  142777: nan},
 'Gust': {142738: 13,
  142739: 14,
  142740: 13,
  142741: 11,
  142742: 15,
  142743: 19,
  142744: 25,
  142745: 19,
  142746: 15,
  142747: 14,
  142748: 10,
  142749: 7,
  142750: 8,
  142751: 7,
  142752: 9,
  142753: 17,
  142754: 26,
  142755: 18,
  142756: 17,
  142757: 14,
  142758: 14,
  142759: 14,
  142760: 24,
  142761: 13,
  142762: 14,
  142763: 13,
  142764: 11,
  142765: 15,
  142766: 19,
  142767: 25,
  142768: 19,
  142769: 15,
  142770: 14,
  142771: 10,
  142772: 7,
  142773: 8,
  142774: 7,
  142775: 9,
  142776: 17,
  142777: 26},
 'Rain': {142738: 0.0,
  142739: 0.0,
  142740: 0.0,
  142741: 0.0,
  142742: 0.0,
  142743: 0.1,
  142744: 0.2,
  142745: 0.1,
  142746: 0.0,
  142747: 0.0,
  142748: 0.1,
  142749: 0.5,
  142750: 1.2,
  142751: 1.0,
  142752: 0.3,
  142753: 0.2,
  142754: 0.0,
  142755: 0.0,
  142756: 0.0,
  142757: 0.0,
  142758: 0.0,
  142759: 0.0,
  142760: 0.0,
  142761: 0.0,
  142762: 0.0,
  142763: 0.0,
  142764: 0.0,
  142765: 0.0,
  142766: 0.1,
  142767: 0.2,
  142768: 0.1,
  142769: 0.0,
  142770: 0.0,
  142771: 0.1,
  142772: 0.5,
  142773: 1.2,
  142774: 1.0,
  142775: 0.3,
  142776: 0.2,
  142777: 0.0},
 'Humidity': {142738: '74%',
  142739: '78%',
  142740: '70%',
  142741: '45%',
  142742: '32%',
  142743: '33%',
  142744: '49%',
  142745: '62%',
  142746: '74%',
  142747: '75%',
  142748: '72%',
  142749: '61%',
  142750: '46%',
  142751: '48%',
  142752: '63%',
  142753: '61%',
  142754: '33%',
  142755: '42%',
  142756: '39%',
  142757: '24%',
  142758: '18%',
  142759: '17%',
  142760: '18%',
  142761: '74%',
  142762: '78%',
  142763: '70%',
  142764: '45%',
  142765: '32%',
  142766: '33%',
  142767: '49%',
  142768: '62%',
  142769: '74%',
  142770: '75%',
  142771: '72%',
  142772: '61%',
  142773: '46%',
  142774: '48%',
  142775: '63%',
  142776: '61%',
  142777: '33%'},
 'Cloud': {142738: nan,
  142739: nan,
  142740: nan,
  142741: nan,
  142742: nan,
  142743: nan,
  142744: nan,
  142745: nan,
  142746: nan,
  142747: nan,
  142748: nan,
  142749: nan,
  142750: nan,
  142751: nan,
  142752: nan,
  142753: nan,
  142754: nan,
  142755: nan,
  142756: nan,
  142757: nan,
  142758: nan,
  142759: nan,
  142760: nan,
  142761: nan,
  142762: nan,
  142763: nan,
  142764: nan,
  142765: nan,
  142766: nan,
  142767: nan,
  142768: nan,
  142769: nan,
  142770: nan,
  142771: nan,
  142772: nan,
  142773: nan,
  142774: nan,
  142775: nan,
  142776: nan,
  142777: nan},
 'Presure': {142738: 1011,
  142739: 1012,
  142740: 1012,
  142741: 1012,
  142742: 1011,
  142743: 1011,
  142744: 1013,
  142745: 1014,
  142746: 1013,
  142747: 1014,
  142748: 1014,
  142749: 1014,
  142750: 1013,
  142751: 1012,
  142752: 1013,
  142753: 1013,
  142754: 1009,
  142755: 1009,
  142756: 1009,
  142757: 1008,
  142758: 1005,
  142759: 1003,
  142760: 1003,
  142761: 1011,
  142762: 1012,
  142763: 1012,
  142764: 1012,
  142765: 1011,
  142766: 1011,
  142767: 1013,
  142768: 1014,
  142769: 1013,
  142770: 1014,
  142771: 1014,
  142772: 1014,
  142773: 1013,
  142774: 1012,
  142775: 1013,
  142776: 1013,
  142777: 1009},
 'Vis': {142738: nan,
  142739: nan,
  142740: nan,
  142741: nan,
  142742: nan,
  142743: nan,
  142744: nan,
  142745: nan,
  142746: nan,
  142747: nan,
  142748: nan,
  142749: nan,
  142750: nan,
  142751: nan,
  142752: nan,
  142753: nan,
  142754: nan,
  142755: nan,
  142756: nan,
  142757: nan,
  142758: nan,
  142759: nan,
  142760: nan,
  142761: nan,
  142762: nan,
  142763: nan,
  142764: nan,
  142765: nan,
  142766: nan,
  142767: nan,
  142768: nan,
  142769: nan,
  142770: nan,
  142771: nan,
  142772: nan,
  142773: nan,
  142774: nan,
  142775: nan,
  142776: nan,
  142777: nan}}
```

```
for i in range(df.date.count()):
    for n in range(df2.Date.count()):
        if df.date[i][0:10]==df2.Date[n]:
            if pd.Timestamp(df.date[i][11:16]).round('180min').to_pydatetime()==df2.Time[n]:
                df['Weather'][i]=df2['Weather'][n]
                df['Temp'][i]=df2['Temp'][n]
                df['Feels'][i]=df2['Feels'][n]
                df['Wind'][i]=df2['Wind'][n]
                df['Gust'][i]=df2['Gust'][n]
                df['Rain'][i]=df2['Rain'][n]
                df['Humidity'][i]=df2['Humidity'][n]
                df['Cloud'][i]=df2['Cloud'][n]
                df['Presure'][i]=df2['Presure'][n]
                df['Vis'][i]=df2['Vis'][n]
```

Comment: Please provide your 2 dataframes as text that can be copy/pasted, and the expected output. You can use `dataframe.to_dict()`

Comment: @mozway both have a lot of data

Comment: then, just a sample or a similar example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Creation of the first dataframe:

  ```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'road': {0: 10500,
                                 1: 10500,
                                 2: 10500,
                                 3: 105400,
                                 4: 105400,
                                 5: 106600,
                                 6: 14100,
                                 7: 22800,
                                 8: 22800,
                                 9: 22800},
                        'date': {0: '2021.03.08 02:00:00',
                                 1: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
                                 2: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
                                 3: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
                                 4: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
                                 5: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
                                 6: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
                                 7: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
                                 8: '2021.03.08 01:45:00',
                                 9: '2021.03.08 05:45:00'}})
    df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by = 'date')
  ```

  ```
       road                date
  3  105400 2021-03-07 21:30:00
  6   14100 2021-03-07 21:30:00
  7   22800 2021-03-07 21:30:00
  8   22800 2021-03-08 01:45:00
  0   10500 2021-03-08 02:00:00
  2   10500 2021-03-08 04:15:00
  1   10500 2021-03-08 05:45:00
  4  105400 2021-03-08 05:45:00
  5  106600 2021-03-08 05:45:00
  9   22800 2021-03-08 05:45:00
  ```
- Creation of the second dataframe:

  ```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Il': {142738: 'ankara',
      142739: 'ankara',
      142740: 'ankara',
      142741: 'ankara',
      142742: 'ankara',
      142743: 'ankara',
      142744: 'ankara',
      142745: 'ankara',
      142746: 'ankara',
      142747: 'ankara',
      142748: 'ankara',
      142749: 'ankara',
      142750: 'ankara',
      142751: 'ankara',
      142752: 'ankara',
      142753: 'ankara',
      142754: 'ankara',
      142755: 'ankara',
      142756: 'ankara',
      142757: 'ankara',
      142758: 'ankara',
      142759: 'ankara',
      142760: 'ankara',
      142761: 'ankara',
      142762: 'ankara',
      142763: 'ankara',
      142764: 'ankara',
      142765: 'ankara',
      142766: 'ankara',
      142767: 'ankara',
      142768: 'ankara',
      142769: 'ankara',
      142770: 'ankara',
      142771: 'ankara',
      142772: 'ankara',
      142773: 'ankara',
      142774: 'ankara',
      142775: 'ankara',
      142776: 'ankara',
      142777: 'ankara'},
     'Lat': {142738: 40.13,
      142739: 40.13,
      142740: 40.13,
      142741: 40.13,
      142742: 40.13,
      142743: 40.13,
      142744: 40.13,
      142745: 40.13,
      142746: 40.13,
      142747: 40.13,
      142748: 40.13,
      142749: 40.13,
      142750: 40.13,
      142751: 40.13,
      142752: 40.13,
      142753: 40.13,
      142754: 40.13,
      142755: 40.13,
      142756: 40.13,
      142757: 40.13,
      142758: 40.13,
      142759: 40.13,
      142760: 40.13,
      142761: 40.13,
      142762: 40.13,
      142763: 40.13,
      142764: 40.13,
      142765: 40.13,
      142766: 40.13,
      142767: 40.13,
      142768: 40.13,
      142769: 40.13,
      142770: 40.13,
      142771: 40.13,
      142772: 40.13,
      142773: 40.13,
      142774: 40.13,
      142775: 40.13,
      142776: 40.13,
      142777: 40.13},
     'Lon': {142738: 33.1,
      142739: 33.1,
      142740: 33.1,
      142741: 33.1,
      142742: 33.1,
      142743: 33.1,
      142744: 33.1,
      142745: 33.1,
      142746: 33.1,
      142747: 33.1,
      142748: 33.1,
      142749: 33.1,
      142750: 33.1,
      142751: 33.1,
      142752: 33.1,
      142753: 33.1,
      142754: 33.1,
      142755: 33.1,
      142756: 33.1,
      142757: 33.1,
      142758: 33.1,
      142759: 33.1,
      142760: 33.1,
      142761: 33.1,
      142762: 33.1,
      142763: 33.1,
      142764: 33.1,
      142765: 33.1,
      142766: 33.1,
      142767: 33.1,
      142768: 33.1,
      142769: 33.1,
      142770: 33.1,
      142771: 33.1,
      142772: 33.1,
      142773: 33.1,
      142774: 33.1,
      142775: 33.1,
      142776: 33.1,
      142777: 33.1},
     'Tarih': {142738: '2021.03.07',
      142739: '2021.03.07',
      142740: '2021.03.07',
      142741: '2021.03.07',
      142742: '2021.03.07',
      142743: '2021.03.07',
      142744: '2021.03.07',
      142745: '2021.03.07',
      142746: '2021.03.07',
      142747: '2021.03.07',
      142748: '2021.03.07',
      142749: '2021.03.07',
      142750: '2021.03.07',
      142751: '2021.03.07',
      142752: '2021.03.07',
      142753: '2021.03.07',
      142754: '2021.03.07',
      142755: '2021.03.07',
      142756: '2021.03.07',
      142757: '2021.03.07',
      142758: '2021.03.07',
      142759: '2021.03.07',
      142760: '2021.03.07',
      142761: '2021.03.08',
      142762: '2021.03.08',
      142763: '2021.03.08',
      142764: '2021.03.08',
      142765: '2021.03.08',
      142766: '2021.03.08',
      142767: '2021.03.08',
      142768: '2021.03.08',
      142769: '2021.03.08',
      142770: '2021.03.08',
      142771: '2021.03.08',
      142772: '2021.03.08',
      142773: '2021.03.08',
      142774: '2021.03.08',
      142775: '2021.03.08',
      142776: '2021.03.08',
      142777: '2021.03.08'},
     'Saat': {142738: '00:00',
      142739: '03:00',
      142740: '06:00',
      142741: '09:00',
      142742: '12:00',
      142743: '15:00',
      142744: '18:00',
      142745: '21:00',
      142746: '00:00',
      142747: '03:00',
      142748: '06:00',
      142749: '09:00',
      142750: '12:00',
      142751: '15:00',
      142752: '18:00',
      142753: '21:00',
      142754: '00:00',
      142755: '03:00',
      142756: '06:00',
      142757: '09:00',
      142758: '12:00',
      142759: '15:00',
      142760: '18:00',
      142761: '00:00',
      142762: '03:00',
      142763: '06:00',
      142764: '09:00',
      142765: '12:00',
      142766: '15:00',
      142767: '18:00',
      142768: '21:00',
      142769: '00:00',
      142770: '03:00',
      142771: '06:00',
      142772: '09:00',
      142773: '12:00',
      142774: '15:00',
      142775: '18:00',
      142776: '21:00',
      142777: '00:00'},
     'Weather': {142738: 1,
      142739: 1,
      142740: 1,
      142741: 1,
      142742: 1,
      142743: 5,
      142744: 5,
      142745: 1,
      142746: 1,
      142747: 1,
      142748: 5,
      142749: 5,
      142750: 11,
      142751: 5,
      142752: 5,
      142753: 1,
      142754: 7,
      142755: 7,
      142756: 4,
      142757: 4,
      142758: 4,
      142759: 1,
      142760: 4,
      142761: 1,
      142762: 1,
      142763: 1,
      142764: 1,
      142765: 1,
      142766: 5,
      142767: 5,
      142768: 1,
      142769: 1,
      142770: 1,
      142771: 5,
      142772: 5,
      142773: 11,
      142774: 5,
      142775: 5,
      142776: 1,
      142777: 7},
     'Temp': {142738: 22,
      142739: 17,
      142740: 18,
      142741: 24,
      142742: 28,
      142743: 28,
      142744: 24,
      142745: 22,
      142746: 18,
      142747: 18,
      142748: 19,
      142749: 22,
      142750: 26,
      142751: 25,
      142752: 21,
      142753: 17,
      142754: 28,
      142755: 21,
      142756: 22,
      142757: 28,
      142758: 32,
      142759: 34,
      142760: 32,
      142761: 22,
      142762: 17,
      142763: 18,
      142764: 24,
      142765: 28,
      142766: 28,
      142767: 24,
      142768: 22,
      142769: 18,
      142770: 18,
      142771: 19,
      142772: 22,
      142773: 26,
      142774: 25,
      142775: 21,
      142776: 17,
      142777: 28},
     'Feels': {142738: 22,
      142739: 17,
      142740: 18,
      142741: 25,
      142742: 28,
      142743: 27,
      142744: 25,
      142745: 22,
      142746: 18,
      142747: 18,
      142748: 19,
      142749: 23,
      142750: 26,
      142751: 26,
      142752: 21,
      142753: 17,
      142754: 31,
      142755: 21,
      142756: 22,
      142757: 26,
      142758: 30,
      142759: 31,
      142760: 31,
      142761: 22,
      142762: 17,
      142763: 18,
      142764: 25,
      142765: 28,
      142766: 27,
      142767: 25,
      142768: 22,
      142769: 18,
      142770: 18,
      142771: 19,
      142772: 23,
      142773: 26,
      142774: 26,
      142775: 21,
      142776: 17,
      142777: 31},
     'Wind': {142738: np.nan,
      142739: np.nan,
      142740: np.nan,
      142741: np.nan,
      142742: np.nan,
      142743: np.nan,
      142744: np.nan,
      142745: np.nan,
      142746: np.nan,
      142747: np.nan,
      142748: np.nan,
      142749: np.nan,
      142750: np.nan,
      142751: np.nan,
      142752: np.nan,
      142753: np.nan,
      142754: np.nan,
      142755: np.nan,
      142756: np.nan,
      142757: np.nan,
      142758: np.nan,
      142759: np.nan,
      142760: np.nan,
      142761: np.nan,
      142762: np.nan,
      142763: np.nan,
      142764: np.nan,
      142765: np.nan,
      142766: np.nan,
      142767: np.nan,
      142768: np.nan,
      142769: np.nan,
      142770: np.nan,
      142771: np.nan,
      142772: np.nan,
      142773: np.nan,
      142774: np.nan,
      142775: np.nan,
      142776: np.nan,
      142777: np.nan},
     'Gust': {142738: 13,
      142739: 14,
      142740: 13,
      142741: 11,
      142742: 15,
      142743: 19,
      142744: 25,
      142745: 19,
      142746: 15,
      142747: 14,
      142748: 10,
      142749: 7,
      142750: 8,
      142751: 7,
      142752: 9,
      142753: 17,
      142754: 26,
      142755: 18,
      142756: 17,
      142757: 14,
      142758: 14,
      142759: 14,
      142760: 24,
      142761: 13,
      142762: 14,
      142763: 13,
      142764: 11,
      142765: 15,
      142766: 19,
      142767: 25,
      142768: 19,
      142769: 15,
      142770: 14,
      142771: 10,
      142772: 7,
      142773: 8,
      142774: 7,
      142775: 9,
      142776: 17,
      142777: 26},
     'Rain': {142738: 0.0,
      142739: 0.0,
      142740: 0.0,
      142741: 0.0,
      142742: 0.0,
      142743: 0.1,
      142744: 0.2,
      142745: 0.1,
      142746: 0.0,
      142747: 0.0,
      142748: 0.1,
      142749: 0.5,
      142750: 1.2,
      142751: 1.0,
      142752: 0.3,
      142753: 0.2,
      142754: 0.0,
      142755: 0.0,
      142756: 0.0,
      142757: 0.0,
      142758: 0.0,
      142759: 0.0,
      142760: 0.0,
      142761: 0.0,
      142762: 0.0,
      142763: 0.0,
      142764: 0.0,
      142765: 0.0,
      142766: 0.1,
      142767: 0.2,
      142768: 0.1,
      142769: 0.0,
      142770: 0.0,
      142771: 0.1,
      142772: 0.5,
      142773: 1.2,
      142774: 1.0,
      142775: 0.3,
      142776: 0.2,
      142777: 0.0},
     'Humidity': {142738: '74%',
      142739: '78%',
      142740: '70%',
      142741: '45%',
      142742: '32%',
      142743: '33%',
      142744: '49%',
      142745: '62%',
      142746: '74%',
      142747: '75%',
      142748: '72%',
      142749: '61%',
      142750: '46%',
      142751: '48%',
      142752: '63%',
      142753: '61%',
      142754: '33%',
      142755: '42%',
      142756: '39%',
      142757: '24%',
      142758: '18%',
      142759: '17%',
      142760: '18%',
      142761: '74%',
      142762: '78%',
      142763: '70%',
      142764: '45%',
      142765: '32%',
      142766: '33%',
      142767: '49%',
      142768: '62%',
      142769: '74%',
      142770: '75%',
      142771: '72%',
      142772: '61%',
      142773: '46%',
      142774: '48%',
      142775: '63%',
      142776: '61%',
      142777: '33%'},
     'Cloud': {142738: np.nan,
      142739: np.nan,
      142740: np.nan,
      142741: np.nan,
      142742: np.nan,
      142743: np.nan,
      142744: np.nan,
      142745: np.nan,
      142746: np.nan,
      142747: np.nan,
      142748: np.nan,
      142749: np.nan,
      142750: np.nan,
      142751: np.nan,
      142752: np.nan,
      142753: np.nan,
      142754: np.nan,
      142755: np.nan,
      142756: np.nan,
      142757: np.nan,
      142758: np.nan,
      142759: np.nan,
      142760: np.nan,
      142761: np.nan,
      142762: np.nan,
      142763: np.nan,
      142764: np.nan,
      142765: np.nan,
      142766: np.nan,
      142767: np.nan,
      142768: np.nan,
      142769: np.nan,
      142770: np.nan,
      142771: np.nan,
      142772: np.nan,
      142773: np.nan,
      142774: np.nan,
      142775: np.nan,
      142776: np.nan,
      142777: np.nan},
     'Presure': {142738: 1011,
      142739: 1012,
      142740: 1012,
      142741: 1012,
      142742: 1011,
      142743: 1011,
      142744: 1013,
      142745: 1014,
      142746: 1013,
      142747: 1014,
      142748: 1014,
      142749: 1014,
      142750: 1013,
      142751: 1012,
      142752: 1013,
      142753: 1013,
      142754: 1009,
      142755: 1009,
      142756: 1009,
      142757: 1008,
      142758: 1005,
      142759: 1003,
      142760: 1003,
      142761: 1011,
      142762: 1012,
      142763: 1012,
      142764: 1012,
      142765: 1011,
      142766: 1011,
      142767: 1013,
      142768: 1014,
      142769: 1013,
      142770: 1014,
      142771: 1014,
      142772: 1014,
      142773: 1013,
      142774: 1012,
      142775: 1013,
      142776: 1013,
      142777: 1009},
     'Vis': {142738: np.nan,
      142739: np.nan,
      142740: np.nan,
      142741: np.nan,
      142742: np.nan,
      142743: np.nan,
      142744: np.nan,
      142745: np.nan,
      142746: np.nan,
      142747: np.nan,
      142748: np.nan,
      142749: np.nan,
      142750: np.nan,
      142751: np.nan,
      142752: np.nan,
      142753: np.nan,
      142754: np.nan,
      142755: np.nan,
      142756: np.nan,
      142757: np.nan,
      142758: np.nan,
      142759: np.nan,
      142760: np.nan,
      142761: np.nan,
      142762: np.nan,
      142763: np.nan,
      142764: np.nan,
      142765: np.nan,
      142766: np.nan,
      142767: np.nan,
      142768: np.nan,
      142769: np.nan,
      142770: np.nan,
      142771: np.nan,
      142772: np.nan,
      142773: np.nan,
      142774: np.nan,
      142775: np.nan,
      142776: np.nan,
      142777: np.nan}})
    df2['date'] = df2['Tarih'] + ' ' + df2['Saat']
    df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by = 'date')
  ```

  ```
              Il    Lat   Lon       Tarih   Saat  Weather  Temp  Feels  Wind  Gust  Rain Humidity  Cloud  Presure  Vis                date
  142738  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  00:00        1    22     22   NaN    13   0.0      74%    NaN     1011  NaN 2021-03-07 00:00:00
  142754  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  00:00        7    28     31   NaN    26   0.0      33%    NaN     1009  NaN 2021-03-07 00:00:00
  142746  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  00:00        1    18     18   NaN    15   0.0      74%    NaN     1013  NaN 2021-03-07 00:00:00
  142739  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  03:00        1    17     17   NaN    14   0.0      78%    NaN     1012  NaN 2021-03-07 03:00:00
  142755  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  03:00        7    21     21   NaN    18   0.0      42%    NaN     1009  NaN 2021-03-07 03:00:00
  142747  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  03:00        1    18     18   NaN    14   0.0      75%    NaN     1014  NaN 2021-03-07 03:00:00
  142740  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  06:00        1    18     18   NaN    13   0.0      70%    NaN     1012  NaN 2021-03-07 06:00:00
  142756  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  06:00        4    22     22   NaN    17   0.0      39%    NaN     1009  NaN 2021-03-07 06:00:00
  142748  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  06:00        5    19     19   NaN    10   0.1      72%    NaN     1014  NaN 2021-03-07 06:00:00
  142749  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  09:00        5    22     23   NaN     7   0.5      61%    NaN     1014  NaN 2021-03-07 09:00:00
  ```
- Merge through [**`pandas.merge_asof`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

  ```
  df = pd.merge_asof(left = df1, right = df2, on = 'date', tolerance = pd.Timedelta('180min'))
  ```

  ```
       road                date      Il    Lat   Lon       Tarih   Saat  Weather  Temp  Feels  Wind  Gust  Rain Humidity  Cloud  Presure  Vis
  0  105400 2021-03-07 21:30:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  21:00        1    22     22   NaN    19   0.1      62%    NaN     1014  NaN
  1   14100 2021-03-07 21:30:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  21:00        1    22     22   NaN    19   0.1      62%    NaN     1014  NaN
  2   22800 2021-03-07 21:30:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.07  21:00        1    22     22   NaN    19   0.1      62%    NaN     1014  NaN
  3   22800 2021-03-08 01:45:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.08  00:00        1    22     22   NaN    13   0.0      74%    NaN     1011  NaN
  4   10500 2021-03-08 02:00:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.08  00:00        1    22     22   NaN    13   0.0      74%    NaN     1011  NaN
  5   10500 2021-03-08 04:15:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.08  03:00        1    17     17   NaN    14   0.0      78%    NaN     1012  NaN
  6   10500 2021-03-08 05:45:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.08  03:00        1    17     17   NaN    14   0.0      78%    NaN     1012  NaN
  7  105400 2021-03-08 05:45:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.08  03:00        1    17     17   NaN    14   0.0      78%    NaN     1012  NaN
  8  106600 2021-03-08 05:45:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.08  03:00        1    17     17   NaN    14   0.0      78%    NaN     1012  NaN
  9   22800 2021-03-08 05:45:00  ankara  40.13  33.1  2021.03.08  03:00        1    17     17   NaN    14   0.0      78%    NaN     1012  NaN
  ```